# how i can create a live streaming server with database and web page?

Tags: laravel, video-streaming, live-streaming

i need to create a live streaming server with videos housed in the same server and the address of the video is specified in an attribute of the database. The problem is i need view the streaming in a website made with laravel framework and change the playlist in the website too. Any suggestion or recomendation of what tool use?

PD: in the server has installed centos 6.4

Comment: Are you wanting live streaming, or just to a video player? If the videos are already stored on your server, and the location stored in your database then it sounds like you're after a regular video player rather than live streaming.

Comment: Both, but the video player it was developed. Now i need use the same videos to create a live streaming with a playlist. Thanks.

Comment: Seems like a big and difficult project to pull through

Comment: At least I need to play videos hosted on the server randomly (In a live streaming). Is it possible to do this using NGINX ?